# How can I optimise this MySQL query?

Tags: php, sql, optimization, mysql

I am using the following MySQL query in a PHP script on a database that contains over 370,000,000 (yes, three hundred and seventy million) rows. I know that it is extremely resource intensive and it takes ages to run this one query. Does anyone know how I can either optimise the query or get the information in another way that's quicker?

Table Info:

```
games | longint, unsigned, Primary Key
win   | bit(1)
loss  | bit(1)
```

Query:

```
SELECT MID(game,{$len},1) AS move,
       COUNT(*) AS games,
       SUM(win) AS wins,
       SUM(loss) AS losses
FROM games
WHERE game>{$something} AND game<{$something_else}
GROUP BY move
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There is something very wrong in using LIKE on a numeric value. Same for that grouping by MID(), it sounds wrong. Why do you do that?

Lastly, rather than having multiple columns for "win" and "loss" why not have a "result" column whose value could be "win", "loss" or "draw".

Comment: It's either a LIKE or a greater than and less than. I didn't think it'd make much difference either way. The grouping by MID() basically groups the next digit in `game`. Same as MID(game,1,{$len}). The win/loss thing takes up 2 bits of space either way so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Using LIKE on numeric values involves type casting, so it has to be less efficient. As for the win/loss columns, I'm afraid they occupy 1 byte each, not just 1 bit.

As for asking "why" perhaps I should have been more specific. The real question is why do you have to query by range, using LIKE, and then group the result using the textual representation of a number. I don't know what data your "games" column actually holds (that's really the kind of things you should describe btw), but it seems that your problem is your database design, not the inefficient queries it has you produce.

Comment: Oh, so columns defined as `bit(1)` still take up a whole byte? That's annoying. The `LIKE` selects only those results that match `$game` (greater than and less than would work too) and then the `GROUP BY` groups them by the next digit. I could also use `GROUP BY FLOOR(game / 10)` for the same effect.

Comment: You don't seem to understand that the problem is not _how_ you do things but rather _why_ you do things. Why do you have to use LIKE to find results and MID() to group them, for instance. What does "game" represent? If it represents more than one thing then you have your problem right there.

Comment: I don't really understand the situation but it seems like you should try to avoid MID and LIKE. What does SELECT MID(game,{$len},1) do? Should it be "SELECT games AS move"? And "WHERE games = '{$game}' GROUP BY games"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only suggestion I can make is to use a table to precalculate all *counts*, and *sums* for each game and update it when table *game* changes using a trigger.

Comment: That would require hundreds of millions more rows than are currently used and more space per row too. The table's already almost 10GiB as it is, so I don't think that's viable.

Comment: But your main problem is that the calculations are too costly. Using some more disk space to build a 'cache' table may help.

Comment: OK, I think I'll look into building some sort of cache system. I'm still worried by the space it'd take up, though.

Answer (score 1):

Straight off the bat, I would stop using the MID() query in both the SELECT expression and GROUP BY. Depening on your query conditions, MySQL will not necessarily cache that inside a single expression whilst parsing, so at least try this:

```
SELECT MID(game,{$len},1) AS move,
   COUNT(*) AS games,
   SUM(win) AS wins,
   SUM(loss) AS losses
   FROM games WHERE game LIKE '{$game}%' GROUP BY move;
```

Not the biggest change in the world, but it should make a small difference. Other than that though, I second that the only real way to optimise this short of changing the way you store the data is to precalculate these values and increment them when a game finishes.

Comment: Oh, great thanks. I didn't realise I could `GROUP BY` a collumn i just made up. Also, I should note that I've changed the `LIKE` to a `> x AND < y` statement.

Comment: You query should run a lot faster with the GROUP BY change, and >'s and <'s instead of LIKE. LIKE uses pattern matching and regular expressions to compute matches, whereas > and < are both boolean operators and be computed using direct assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try starting with the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) query or [profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're read heavy, consider keep and maintain an aggregated table over the data you commonly query.

Comment: Unfortunately I use all different vales for `$game` with approximately equal frequency.

Comment: That just means you aggregate upon the different values of $games that you will need. even if that ranges in the millions, it'll likely be a lot less than the individual records.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you could denormalize this and create a "moves" table, recording stats per "move", not only per "game".

Answer (score 0):

You can "buy speed" by sacrificing storage space or onserve storage space but got worse performance. As your problem is speed, you'll need some precalculations. And yes, some profiling of the query.

BTW, the "big ones" used to have different configs (different hardware and settings) for OLTP (serving the actual transactions in real time) and DW (analysing large amounts of data).

Answer (score 0):

The mid() function  is what is killing this query.
MySQL has to create a temp table in memory to deal with the mid() function and do filesort on that table because of the group by.

I'm assuming that $game is the type of game. (checkers, chess, tic tac toe)

I would hang another table off for the type of game. This allows your group to make use of an index which would be much faster.

I suggest something like:

```
[game]
game bigint unsigned
win bit
loss bit
game_type_id bigint unsigned

[game_type]
game_type_id bigint unsigned
game_type_desc varchar(13)
```

Be careful with alters statements on a table this large. 
Always make a backup before you issue an alter.

Comment: Actually, `$game` is a 15 digit long quinary number. :P
Also, as it says in the question, MID() has to be able to accept 5 different length values so that would be one HUGE extra table!

Comment: Its creating part of the huge extra table in memory every time the query is run and not giving you the benefit of an index.